# How do i solve flutter doctor error saying connected device (the doctor check crashed)?

Tags: android, flutter

When I am trying to run flutter doctor it shows me that

```
   "Connected  devices (the doctor check crashed)
    Due to an error, the doctor Check did not complete."
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Similar to this? https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49196

Comment: Yes almost same but not exactly same i am getting on more error after that saying

Comment: Exception: unable to run ' adb' , check your android sdk installation and ANDROID_SDK_ROOT

Comment: The Android studio Installation is what causing the error. Please make sure, the SDK is properly installed,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that a problem when you try to build your app an emulator or device? Otherwise if you have no device or emulator on connection, flutter doctor gives that error. I have that error too but this is not a problem.

Comment: I am trying to add my mobile but it is not showing as it is connected and it is giving one more error saying

Comment: Exception: unable to run ' adb' , check your android sdk installation and ANDROID_SDK_ROOT –

Answer (score 5):

go to C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
`where your adb located`

delete the file of  `platform-tools`

go to

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools
download the lastest  platform-tools  it about 15 Mb

extract it and copy to to C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools