# How can I solve the "Flutter doctor" problem?

Tags: flutter

[image]

The following appears when I enter "flutter doctor"

[☠] Flutter (the doctor check crashed)
X Due to an error, the doctor check did not complete. If the error message below is not helpful, please let us know
about this issue at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.
X Exception: Cannot find the executable for `where`. This can happen if the System32 folder (e.g.
C:\Windows\System32 ) is removed from the PATH environment variable. Ensure that this is present and then try
again after restarting the terminal and/or IDE.

instalarlo de nuevo lo resolverá?

Comment: Did you try doing what the error recommended?

Comment: Hi please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64910296/8682142) answer

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have add C:\Windows\System32 path System variables.
2. Make sure you have latest Flutter SDK
3. also try to run flutter doctor in android studio terminal
4. Restart Terminal and android studio after any path update in
   environment variable

Comment: https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-and-configure-flutter-sdk-windows-10/
please follow steps 3 onward..